# to give whatever figures in another cell

Tags: excel

To the formula below at the bottom, I want to add the parameter `if(and(AJ2187="",AQ2187=>1)=AQ2187`;
So, if `AJ` is empty and `AQ` is greater or equal to 1, it to give whatever the result is in `AQ`, but excel tells me that there are too many arguments. Is the `=AQ2187` I have put not right?

`IF(AJ2187="","",IF(COUNTIF(AJ$2:AJ2187,AJ2187)=1,SUMIF($AJ$2:$AJ$11972,$AJ2187,AQ$2:$AQ12524),""))`

Answer (score 0):

If the 2nd condition is not met, the cell will be blank

You'll want just this part

```
IF(AQ2187=>1, AQ2187, "")
```

to replace the `""` after the first IF condition, so it will look like this

```
IF(AJ2187="",IF(AQ2187=>1, AQ2187, ""),IF(COUNTIF(AJ$2:AJ2187,AJ2187)=1,SUMIF($AJ$2:$AJ$11972,$AJ2187,AQ$2:$AQ12524),""))
```